# Nginx API subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, nginx, server

I've just created sub-domain for API usage. Now it looks like api.example.com and everything works fine. However I would like to forbit access to html views from api.example.com. It should response on api calls only.

```
scope module: 'web' do
    root 'home#index'
end

constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api' do
        scope module: 'v1' do

        end
    end
end
```

I guess I can achieve it via build appropriate location directive

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        rails_env production;
        root /home/example/current/public;

        server_name api.example.com;
        #location ???
}
```

Below block for example.com domain:

```
server {
          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80;

          rails_env production;
          root /home/example/current/public;

          server_name example.com;
          error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

          location = /50x.html {
              root   html;
          }

}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to do *anything* in nginx. It will be all handled by your rails router.

Say, you have this code:

```
scope module: 'web' do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :articles
end

constraints subdomain: 'api' do
  scope module: 'api' do
    scope module: 'v1' do
      resources :articles
    end
  end
end
```

Your web articles controller serves html. If you try to access it via api subdomain (`http://api.example.com/articles/1`), you'll get a 404, because this route is not defined for this constraint. You can only do `http://api.example.com/api/v1/articles/1` which renders json, not html.

Comment: I forgot to add but it's subdomian of subdomian: api.subdomain.example.com. Example.com is on other vps than subdomian.example.com and api.subdomain.example.com . However is the same LAN

Comment: Makes little difference. Instead of having `web` constraint, you can have a one-line check in a `before_action` which will check subdomain - it's a web controller but api subdomain - redirect or render 404 or whatever.

Comment: So main DNS server indicates both domains (subdomian and api.subdomain) as the same ip address

Comment: Also, it seems rather easy with nginx too: just reject all locations which don't begin with `/api/v1`. But my nginx-fu is not good enough to provide this answer :)

Comment: The same to me. I am new to nginx but I would like to do it in nginx rather than rails app